# Mental illnesses in Carrie's family

Tags: character, homeland

In *Homeland*, Carrie and her dad have bipolar disorder.

Does Carrie's niece have ADHD?

This is based on the drug, Adderall that

> Carrie stole in S07E03.

In the same scene, there is a bottle of Ritalin next to the Adderall.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were never shown any further evidence during the show, nor the subject is discussed. Apparently (medically speaking) it's also not that simple, we can't know for sure if she has or not based on her behaviour on the show.

Comment: The alternative is that Carrie's niece has narcolepsy or some other mental or neurological illness that is treated with methylphenidate?

Comment: @BCLC how would we know? it was never a plot point and we're trying to figure it out based on one split second scene... How is that relevant to character or plot development anyway?

Comment: (This is not really movies/series but medical based on something you brought up in the 1st part of your 2nd sentence.) Methylphenidate generally treats ADHD afaik, so when you say we're not sure, I just wanna double check that you're referring to the fact that methylphenidate's uses are not limited to ADHD.

Comment: Yup. Since I'm not a doctor I was googling for ADHD symptoms before answering and apparently it's not easy to diagnose ADHD just by analysing the behavior, also the medication could be for something else indeed.

Comment: ayt. thanks for answering and for the clarification.